# Block copy paste option in Excel, using python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to lock the copy paste cell option in an excel file generated using python ?
I have used XLSXWriter to generate the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you would probably use [Worksheet Protect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/copy-and-paste-in-a-protected-worksheet-139e676e-10a0-443b-bbfe-3dac22cd8476?ui=en-us&rs=en-ie&ad=ie) to prevent copying of data into a worksheet.

You can do this with XlsxWriter using the worksheet [protect()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect) method. Here is an example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('protection.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create some cell formats with protection properties.
unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
hidden = workbook.add_format({'hidden': True})

# Format the columns to make the text more visible.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect()

# Write a locked, unlocked and hidden cell.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Cell B1 is locked. It cannot be edited.')
worksheet.write('A2', 'Cell B2 is unlocked. It can be edited.')
worksheet.write('A3', "Cell B3 is hidden. The formula isn't visible.")

worksheet.write_formula('B1', '=1+2')  # Locked by default.
worksheet.write_formula('B2', '=1+2', unlocked)
worksheet.write_formula('B3', '=1+2', hidden)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this hinders pasting to that cell but doesnt block a user from copying data from those cells

Comment: So how do you prevent copying data into a worksheet in Excel?